# how expand rectangle after detected faces opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I write code and i want How to expand the rectangle after the detection of the faces to     up to the head and neck of human

```
    #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>  //this code detetced faces ///
    #include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>///////////
    #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
     ////////////////////
    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {

        CascadeClassifier cascade;

        if (!cascade.load("haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml"))  //load harcascade xml
            return -1;

         Mat src = imread("11.jpg");  //read image 

        if (src.empty())
            return -1;
    cv::resize(src,src,cv::Size(600,600));  resize image 
        Mat gray;
        cvtColor(src, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        equalizeHist(gray, gray);

        vector<Rect> faces;
        cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, faces, 1.2, 3,0,Size(30,30));

        for (size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
        {
     /////////////////////////////
            Rect r = faces[i];
    //////////////////////////////       

              Mat faceROI = gray( faces[i] );
          int x = faces[i].x;
          int y = faces[i].y;
          int h =0.3*y+faces[i].height;
          int w = faces[i].width;
          printf("Orig dimensions after h * w crop 1: %dx%d\n",h,w);
            printf("Orig dimensions after  x* y crop 2: %dx%d\n",x,y);

           rectangle(src,Point (x,y),Point(x + w,y +h),Scalar(255,0,255),1,4,0);
             imshow("mmmmmmmmmmm.jpg",src );  //show image in windows 
        }
    ///////////////////////////////

        waitKey(0);

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to adjust the height and starting y coordinate appropriately.

On a short look, I felt height of box should be increases by a factor of 0.3 on both the sides (top and bottom). So I subtracted `0.3*h` from `y` and added `0.3*2*h` (i.e. 0.6*h) to `h`.

It is just my rough calculation. For fine adjustment, you analyze it for different faces and come up with a measurement that best suits your purpose.

Here is the changed code:

```
int x = faces[i].x;
int h_temp = faces[i].height;    // storing original height
int y = faces[i].y - h_temp*0.3; // y is reduced by 0.3*h
int w = faces[i].width;
int h = h_temp*1.6;              // height is increases by 60%
```

And below is the result I got for example. Green shows original I got. Blue is the modified:

[image: face detection example]

Remember, how much you want to select, depends on you. Make adjustments to above values to get your required result.

Comment: Most welcome. Does it work for you? If so, you can accept this answer by clicking the tick sign near my answer and close this session. If not solved, you can mention your problem as comments here. (I see from your profile, you are new to SOF. That is why I reminded this).

Answer (score 17):

To expand the OpenCV faces rectangle, you can also use below operators([1](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?wb48617274=360FE5C1#rect)) to `cv::Rect` class

```
//expanding or shrinking a rectangle by a certain amount
cv::Rect += cv::Size
//shifting a rectangle by a certain offset
cv::Rect -= cv::Point
```

Example for expanding face rectangle by 10% would be

```
cv::Size deltaSize( faces[i].width * 0.1f, faces[i].height * 0.1f ); // 0.1f = 10/100
cv::Point offset( deltaSize.width/2, deltaSize.height/2);
faces[i] += deltaSize;
faces[i] -= offset;
```