# How to Enlarge each rectangle (boundingbox) from findcontour Opencv C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a program to detect an Image using bounding box. But, somehow only the center of the image (which have a high saturation) can detect. I want to enlarge the bounding box so the object with low saturation can be detect too.Here is the image [image result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soNpX.png)

The red rectangle is the result of boundingbox from findcontour. I want the rectangle like the blue one, so the large object can be detected. Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


int main(){

Mat frame = imread("32.jpg", 1); 
Mat mask(frame.size(), CV_8UC1, Scalar::all(0));
Mat hsv;
int a = 5;
cv::cvtColor(frame, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);

std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;
split(hsv, channels);

cv::Mat H = channels[0];
cv::Mat S = channels[1];
cv::Mat V = channels[2];

Mat th;
threshold(S, th, 90, 255, THRESH_OTSU);

vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
/// Find contours
findContours(th, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, Point(0, 0));
vector<Rect> rekt(contours.size());

/// Draw contours
Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(th.size(), CV_8UC3);

for (int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++)
{
    if (cv::contourArea(contours[i]) < 500) continue;
    rekt[i] = boundingRect(Mat(contours[i]));

    rectangle(mask, rekt[i].tl(), rekt[i].br(), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2, 8, 0);
}

imshow("ori", frame);
imshow("olaaa", resImage);

waitKey(0);
}
```

I have tried the other code such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25310342/how-to-correctly-increase-the-size-of-rectangle-found-with-cvfindcontours) and this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894110/how-expand-rectangle-after-detected-faces-opencv) but the image doesn't show the rectangle and only show black background.
Thankyou.

Comment: Can you include the original input image?

Comment: Try adjusting threshold values to include the silhouettes to binary image `th`. At this point, you can eliminate the small blobs by [morphological opening](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html). Then, you can find contours and draw bounding boxes around them.

Comment: okeey, thankyou @eldesgraciado and Burak for your answer. My original image is the image result, but without the bounding box. I'll try to do something with the threshold and morphological opening. Thanks a lot for your answer. It's really help me